# MMQGIS geocoding location error in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mmqgis

I´m getting a locational error during the process of geocoding a csv file (with 3 records) with MMQGIS in QGIS 2.18.

The error is that the geocoding result are in the same locational place.

I already made the geocoding with Google and OpenStreeMap servers, having the same error. Any ideas...?

I´m using a single csv file (UTF-8 encoded) with 5 records (3 in Comodoro Rivadavia city, 1 in Puerto Madryn city and 1 in Trelew city). Sorry but I don´t know how to add a screen shot here. It´s seems that the geocoding is well done in a City scale, but not so good with the addresses detail (in the city where we have 3 addresses, the 3 of them are in the same spot.

CSV detail: Direccion;Ciudad;Provincia;Pais Belgrano 574;Comodoro Rivadavia;Chubut;Argentina Sarmiento 230;Comodoro Rivadavia;Chubut;Argentina Belgrano 874;Comodoro Rivadavia;Chubut;Argentina Libertad 147;Puerto Madryn;Chubut;Argentina Laprida 147;Trelew;Chubut;Argentina

Comment: Can you share the error that you see?

Comment: The error is that all records appear located in the same spot (instead of each one in the correct address). Just to try an alterntive, I add a record of a near city, I was located in the city but not in the address. It seems that the records are well located in the city field, but not in the correct address. The city where I have the 3 records all appear in the same spot.

Comment: Please provide more details. What specific data are you using as input and parameters?

Comment: I´m using a single csv file (UTF-8 encoded) with 5 records (3 in Comodoro Rivadavia city, 1 in Puerto Madryn city and 1 in Trelew city). Sorry but I don´t know how to add a screen shot here. It´s seems that the geocoding is well done in a City scale, but not so good with the addresses detail (in the city where we have 3 addresses, the 3 of them are in the same spot.

Comment: CSV detail: Direccion;Ciudad;Provincia;Pais
Belgrano 574;Comodoro Rivadavia;Chubut;Argentina
Sarmiento 230;Comodoro Rivadavia;Chubut;Argentina
Belgrano 874;Comodoro Rivadavia;Chubut;Argentina
Libertad 147;Puerto Madryn;Chubut;Argentina
Laprida 147;Trelew;Chubut;Argentina